# Navigator Plugin development - Session expiration

Tags: javascript, filenet-p8, ibm-content-navigator

I'm working on a plugin for ICN and I've managed to have it log in automatically retrieving the username/password from a file by an id which is passed as a parameter in the url. Once a user has logged in there will be no need to relog, however after some time the 'session expiration' will kick in and even after reloading I can't get it to log in again. This might be due to the fact that I'm basing my decision on a single javascript object: **ecm.model.desktop.connected**.

Right now if **ecm.model.desktop.connected** is **false** it will try to log in, this works well until the session expiration, which apparently does not set the **ecm.model.desktop.connected** to false, it's still set to true. So I'm hoping to learn a way to tell if the session has expired.

This here is my login code:

```
if (ecm.model.desktop.connected == false || ecm.model.desktop.userId != loginConfig[loginID].username) {
     var http2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var url2 = "/navigator/logon.do";
     var params2 = "userid=" + loginConfig[loginID].username + "&password=" + loginConfig[loginID].password;
     http2.open("POST", url2, false);
     http2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     http2.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
          if (http2.readyState == 4 && http2.status == 200) {

          }
     };
     http2.send(params2);
     window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a workaround avoiding session expiration entirely using a cookie set to expire in 'x' minutes making a sort of session of my own.
First I check if the cookie is created, if it's not it means it either expired or was never created in the first place, so I create it and make a synchronous POST call to logoff.do and reload() the site.

Once created and after reloading I check if the cookie exists once again, since it does I check if ecm.model.desktop.connected is false or the user is trying to log in with a different ID. If that occurs I'll have it log in making a synchronous POST call to logon.do with the proper username/password and then reload().

All done the user has now access to the features offered by my plugin.